# Not able to center D3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to draw [a circle with different data values](https://jsfiddle.net/u2x7ncns/5/) as angles but for some reason, it's only the last data point that gets the color and display. I've tried to translate the svg but it seems not to budge.

I'm fairly new to D3 so I'm sure I've done something less intelligent without realizing it. As far I could tell, the angles in the *g* and *path* elements are as supposed to.

```
var height = 400, width = 600, radius = Math.min(height, width) / 2;
var colors = ["#red", "pink", "green", "yellow", "blue","magent","brown","olive","orange"];
var data = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,1];

var chart = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
chart.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) { return d; });
var arc = d3.svg.arc().startAngle(0).innerRadius(0).outerRadius(radius);

var grx = chart.selectAll(".sector").data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g").attr("class", "sector");

grx.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function (d, i) {
    console.log(d);
    return colors[i];
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending all the sectors of the pie to the `svg` node when they should be appended to the translated `g` node, you have two options to solve this problem

- make `chart` equal to the translated `g` node
- select `g` before all the `.sectors` and store that in `grx`

The first solution is simpler e.g.

```
var chart = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6kvbzd5g/)

Comment: Right, I think I see it. Still, I'm pretty sure I do something wrong with the assignments as all we can see in your demo is a bright, orange sun. Should be a pie chart... What more am I missing?

Comment: I think I see why I'm getting what I'm getting. It's because the starting angle of the next segment is zero. It should be the ending angle of the previous one. I can ask that as a separate question.